# How to union two Observable. Rx 6.2.2

Tags: typescript, rxjs6

I have two calls to the backend and I need handle result only when both responses will be ready:

```
this.historyService.fetchBalance().subscribe((balance: Balance[]) => {
    this.servicesBalance = balance;
});

this.historyService.fetchOuts().subscribe((outs: History[]) => {
    this.outHistories = outs;
});
```

I know `forkJoin` method but it returns Array and I lost types, something like this:

```
...subscribe([v1, v2] => ...)
```

I want to save types of returning values something like this:

```
...subscribe(balance: Balance[], outs: History[] => ...)
```

How to union Observables in my case?

```
myQuestionUnionMethod(
    this.historyService.fetchBalance(),
    this.historyService.fetchOuts()
)
    .subscribe(balance: Balance[], outs: History[] => ...)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried `zip`? It seems [properly typed](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/8fbb15e7f4b699fe5c5d10cb31bfe81595a51697/src/internal/observable/zip.ts#L26):

```
export function zip<T, T2>(v1: ObservableInput<T>, v2: ObservableInput<T2>): Observable<[T, T2]>;
export function zip<T, T2, T3>(v1: ObservableInput<T>, v2: ObservableInput<T2>, v3: ObservableInput<T3>): Observable<[T, T2, T3]>;
export function zip<T, T2, T3, T4>(v1: ObservableInput<T>, v2: ObservableInput<T2>, v3: ObservableInput<T3>, v4: ObservableInput<T4>): Observable<[T, T2, T3, T4]>;
export function zip<T, T2, T3, T4, T5>(v1: ObservableInput<T>, v2: ObservableInput<T2>, v3: ObservableInput<T3>, v4: ObservableInput<T4>, v5: ObservableInput<T5>): Observable<[T, T2, T3, T4, T5]>;
export function zip<T, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6>(v1: ObservableInput<T>, v2: ObservableInput<T2>, v3: ObservableInput<T3>, v4: ObservableInput<T4>, v5: ObservableInput<T5>, v6: ObservableInput<T6>): Observable<[T, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6]>;
```

On second thought, `forkJoin` also seems properly typed:

```
export function forkJoin<T>(sources: [ObservableInput<T>]): Observable<T[]>;
export function forkJoin<T, T2>(sources: [ObservableInput<T>, ObservableInput<T2>]): Observable<[T, T2]>;
export function forkJoin<T, T2, T3>(sources: [ObservableInput<T>, ObservableInput<T2>, ObservableInput<T3>]): Observable<[T, T2, T3]>;
export function forkJoin<T, T2, T3, T4>(sources: [ObservableInput<T>, ObservableInput<T2>, ObservableInput<T3>, ObservableInput<T4>]): Observable<[T, T2, T3, T4]>;
export function forkJoin<T, T2, T3, T4, T5>(sources: [ObservableInput<T>, ObservableInput<T2>, ObservableInput<T3>, ObservableInput<T4>, ObservableInput<T5>]): Observable<[T, T2, T3, T4, T5]>;
export function forkJoin<T, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6>(sources: [ObservableInput<T>, ObservableInput<T2>, ObservableInput<T3>, ObservableInput<T4>, ObservableInput<T5>, ObservableInput<T6>]): Observable<[T, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6]>;
export function forkJoin<T>(sources: Array<ObservableInput<T>>): Observable<T[]>;
```

What makes you think the return value is not properly typed? Do you have an example where you "lost types"?

Comment: what different between forkJoin and zip?